# How can I list last updated packages from terminal?

Tags: apt, updates

After upgrading packages my system is not booting anymore. How can I list last updated packages from terminal in order to revert the changes?
Or is there a simpler way to take back latest upgrade?

Comment: From LiveCD/USB look in /var/log/apt/history.log where what is installed is shown date-wise. Whether knowing that will help you, I don't know.

Comment: you mean update, right? which command you executed? `apt-get update`,`apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Command to list recently installed packages that were installed via any method (apt-get, Software Center...):

`cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "`

**Example output:**

```
2010-12-08 15:48:14 install python-testtools <none> 0.9.2-1
2010-12-08 15:48:16 install quickly-widgets <none> 10.09
2010-12-08 22:21:31 install libobasis3.3-sdk <none> 3.3.0-17
2010-12-09 12:00:24 install mc <none> 3:4.7.0.6-1
2010-12-09 23:32:06 install oggconvert <none> 0.3.3-1ubuntu1
2010-12-09 23:34:50 install mpg123 <none> 1.12.1-3ubuntu1
2010-12-09 23:34:52 install dir2ogg <none> 0.11.8-1
2010-12-09 23:34:53 install faad <none> 2.7-4
2010-12-09 23:34:54 install wavpack <none> 4.60.1-1
2010-12-10 11:53:00 install playonlinux <none> 3.8.6
```

---

Command to list history of `apt-get` (NOTE: this doesn't list dependencies installed, it simply lists previous `apt-get` commands that were run):

`cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "\ install\ "`

**Example output:**

```
Commandline: apt-get install libindicate-doc
Commandline: apt-get install googlecl
Commandline: apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Commandline: apt-get install valac libvala-0.10-dev
Commandline: apt-get install libgtksourceview-dev
Commandline: apt-get install python-sphinx
Commandline: apt-get install python-epydoc
Commandline: apt-get install quickly-widgets
Commandline: apt-get install libreoffice3* libobasis3.3*
Commandline: apt-get install mc
```

Comment: Does this also list upgraded packages?

Comment: yes of course because in the upgrade process the upgraded packages will be installed. You can also change the command like this to check for more info : grep  "\ upgrade\ "

Comment: As of 16.04, it is "\ installed\ " not "\ install\ ".

Comment: Nowadays the correct commnad should be: 
`cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ upgrade\ "`